# Vuetify v-dialog not showing the second time

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I'm trying to to conditionally show a dialog. The dialog shows up the first time just fine.
But when second time I try to remount the component I can't see the dialog.
The dialog also fetches some data when it is mounted. I can see the logs that the dialog is being mounted and unmounted and also the network request on chrome devtools network tab but I can't see the dialog.

**index.vue**

```html
<v-list-item-title @click="changeDialogState">
<TestDialog 
        v-if="showEditDialog"
        :id="item.id"
        @editDone="changeDialogState"/>
       Edit
</v-list-item-title>

------------------------
//This is defined inside methods
changeDialogState() {
      this.showEditDialog = !this.showEditDialog // this.showEditDialog is just a boolean value define inside data()
},
```

**Testdialog.vue**

```html
<template>
  <v-dialog v-model="dialog" width="700">
    <v-progress-circular
      v-if="fetching"
      :size="70"
      :width="7"
      color="purple"
      indeterminate
    ></v-progress-circular>

    <v-card v-else>
      <v-card-title> New Customer </v-card-title>
      <v-divider></v-divider>
      <v-card-text>
        <customer-form
          v-model="customer"
          :errors="errors"
          :initial-customer="customer"
          @submit="editCustomer"
        >
          <template v-slot:footer>
            <v-card-actions>
              <v-spacer></v-spacer>
              <v-btn text @click="$emit('editDone')"> Cancel </v-btn>
              <v-btn color="primary" type="submit" class="ma-1">
                Save Customer
              </v-btn>
            </v-card-actions>
          </template>
        </customer-form>
      </v-card-text>
    </v-card>
  </v-dialog>
</template>

<script>
import { formHandling, paginatedResponse } from '~/mixins'
export default {
  mixins: [formHandling, paginatedResponse],
  props: {
    value: {
      type: Object,
      default: () => ({
        //some stuff here
      }),
    },
    error: {
      type: Array,
      required: true,
      default: () => {
        return []
      },
    },
    id: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
  },

  async fetch() {
    this.fetching = true
    this.customer = await this.$axios.$get(`/customer/${this.id}/`)
    this.fetching = false
  },
  data() {
    return {
      dialog: true,
      customer: {
        ...
      },
      errors: {
        ...
      },
      fetching: true,
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log('TestDialog - mounted')
  },
  beforeDestroy() {
    console.log('TestDialog - unmounted')
  },
  methods: {
    async editCustomer(customer) {
      try {
        await this.$axios.$put(`/customer/${this.id}/`, customer)
        this.dialog = false
      } catch (err) {
        this.setErrors(err)
      }
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

Comment: First of, you can ditch the `fetching` boolean in favor of `$fetchState.pending`, this helper is available when using the `fetch()` hook, no need to do it yourself. Then, what do you mean when you say `I try to remount the component`? Can you console.log the `dialog` boolean on `mounted()` please? Vue devtools can also help here!

Comment: Also, is both `showEditDialog` and `dialog` useful here? Can't you remove one of them?

Comment: Thanks for `$fetchState.pending` I was unware of that.
`I try to remount the component` By that I mean when I change the value of `showEditDialog`  it should (render/not render) the component based on it's boolean value.
And about `showEditDialog`, it's for conditionally rendering the element. and `dialog` is there because I was modifying value of `dialog`  when I was experimenting and changing props is not a good practice.